# Finger slide on screen method

Tags: android, sdk

Is there a  built-in method in the sdk for eclipse for example like `onClick` or `OnPause`, but finger slide, that has `OnSlideUp` and down and left and right?

it will spare me alot of time if there is, so i wouldnt have to built one myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android you can use the GestureDetector.OnGestureListener to detect gestures, there is not a specific onSlideUp but there is a onFling and a onTouch that you can use. Just have your Activity implement the listener.

A quick onFling example method:

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, 
        float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onFling: " + event1.toString()+event2.toString());
    return true;
}
```

Android Documentation link for handling gestures: 
https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html#detect